# How to change the choice list in ui-select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I have a basic ui-select component, and a case to take another list for ui-select.

How do I change here "`somelist`" into "`anotherlist`" when button clicked or by some another function call)?

```
<ui-select ng-model="obj.selected"> 
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.dsc}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat=" X in somelist | propsFilter: {dsc: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="X.dsc | highlight: $select.search" position='down'></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<button>Change list</button>
```

Comment: Write `anotherlist` instead of  `somelist`. :O

Comment: Programmatically?

Comment: There has to be some condition around it, right? Do an ng-if or ng-show/hide based on the condition.

Comment: @sisyphus, do you mean to write all ui-select tag twice with ng-if?

Comment: `<button ng-click="somelist = ['new item']">Change list</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution;

I guess ui-select refreshes when `somelist` gets `undefined` and then gets filled again. So this worked for me:

```
somelist = undefined;
somelist = anotherlist;
```